# How to transfer data from a html page to another html page in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm building buy function in my website and i want when the user click the buy button, the information of the product (productName and price) will auto fill in the input of the bill form, i tried to use @PathVariable and @RequestParam but it seems doesn't work.

this is product.html

```
<div th:each="product:${food}">
    <form th:action="@{/payment}">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${product.productName}" th:name="productName"></h5>
          <p class="card-text" th:text="${product.description}" th:name="description"></p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${product.productType}" th:name="productType"></li>
          <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${product.price}" th:name="price"></li>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

this is the function in Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/payment")
    public String buy(@RequestParam("productName") String name, @RequestParam("price") Float price, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("price", price);
        return "payment";
    }
```

What did i wrong in the syntax or do we have anyway to transfer data from the html pages? Thanks u guys a lot

Comment: See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/ for more information on how Thymeleaf form handling works.

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag you missed the object to be transmitted to your controller. All the field from your form need to be place in an object which will be catched by your controller thanks to the annotation @ModelAttribute.
It will look like:

```
<form th:action="@{/payment}" th:object="${product}" >....
```

and in your controller:

```
  public String buy(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, Model model) {...}
```